# Why is it possible initialize java.util.function.Consumer with lambda that returns value?

Tags: java-8

Although functional interface Consumer has abstract method `void accept(T t);`, it is possible to initialize it the following way:

```
Consumer<String> stringConsumer = s -> s.length();
// or 
Consumer<String> stringConsumer = String::length;
```

... where `String.length()` returns `int`. Return types do not match in this case. Why is it allowed?

P.S. Compiler will not allow to operate with such Consumer as with Function. The following line will not compile.

```
System.out.println(stringConsumer.accept("Hello!"));
```

Comment: Because it's allowed, and often normal, to ignore the return value of a method. For example, how often do you care about the boolean value returned by Set.add()? Almost never, right? So you call it as if it returned void.

Comment: You can read the JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8 here if you want... there 4 types that are allowed.

Comment: @JB Nizet: it’s even less likely that someone is interested in the result of `List.add()` ;-)