# Can forEach method in Java Stream take a Function functional interface as argument

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream, consumer, functional-interface

I am not quite able to understand why the `line1` and `line2` in the following code compiles just fine? Can `forEach` method in Java `Stream` take a `Function` functional interface as argument?

On `line 1`, shouldn't the `IntConsumer` functional interface that `forEach` takes have a `void` return whereas the `value1.incrementAndGet()` does return a `long`?

Similarly, wouldn't `++value2[0]` return a  `long` and make the code not compile?

```
public class ShouldItCompile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicLong value1 = new AtomicLong(0);
        final long[] value2 = {0};
        IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 1).limit(100).parallel().forEach(i -> value1.incrementAndGet());//line1
        IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 1).limit(100).parallel().forEach(i -> ++value2[0]);//line2
        System.out.println(value1+" "+value2[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced type inference rules are indistinguishable from magic" - not Arthur C Clarke.

Comment: [Why is it possible initialize java.util.function.Consumer with lambda that returns value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103851/why-is-it-possible-initialize-java-util-function-consumer-with-lambda-that-retur?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [Method Reference - passing Function to method with Consumer argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377771/method-reference-passing-function-to-method-with-consumer-argument)